.NET 8 IFormFile always return null
When uploading a file in a form post operation, the IFormFile parameter always returns null. When I try it with the basic project version in a simple operation, it reads the file and does not return null.  enctype="multipart/form-data" input type="file" name="file"
Controller code:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> File([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", file.FileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    return Content($"File uploaded");
}

How can I solve this?

@erayyal: Can you add your view content including the <form> code to the post, please?

it reads the file and does not return . --> what does it mean? [FromForm] IFormFile file -> the file is null?

I can reproduce your issue in my side in the next 2 scenarios: 1 we used a wrong file variable name like <input type="file" name="file1" /> but the correct one should be name="file"; 2 when I didn't set enctype="multipart/form-data" which would make the submition have content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded which should be multipart/form-data

as a side note, you should be in full control of the filename and extension.  (unless you can trust all your users)

Because of the File() action method looks acceptable and the question doesn't contain the view code, see the minimal code for posting a file:
<form asp-controller="your_controller" asp-action="File" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


Here's the test result of your action method. Just like what you can see, it worked well when we choose to post a form. So the backend code is correct.

According to your description, I'm afraid the issue is due to model binding failure -> we have variable name file in action method, so that if we use the form element like <input type="file" name="file1" />, we will get null exception. The second possible issue is that we didn't set enctype="multipart/form-data" for the form. See my test below. Without this configuration, the content type shall be application/x-www-form-urlencoded which will cause the issue too.


